# LINQ To Sql Update Inside Loop

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq-to-sql

My question is this, if I loop through my collection, shown below, and set the values appropriately would I need to call `dc.SubmitChanges()` at the end of each iteration for it to work properly?  Wouldn't it simply overwrite the previous values on Update if I don't?

I am passing a `Contact` object to this `Save()` method.  That object has a `PersonContact` property which in turn has a `Phones` property.  This is the portion of the `Save()` method that needs to loop through the `Phones` in my object and compare them with the `DB` and take appropriate action.

Is there a better, simpler way?

```
If contact.PersonContact.Phones IsNot Nothing Then
  For Each phone In contact.PersonContact.Phones
    Dim exists = dc.tblPhones.SingleOrDefault(Function(p) p.ID = phone.ID)
    If exists IsNot Nothing Then
        If phone.Number = String.Empty AndAlso phone.Extension = String.Empty Then
            'Delete
            dc.tblPhones.DeleteOnSubmit(exists)
        Else
            'Update
            exists.ID = phone.ID
            exists.PhoneNumber = phone.Number
            exists.TypeID = phone.TypeID
            exists.UpdateDate = DateTime.Now
            exists.UpdateUser = user
        End If
    Else
        'Insert
        exists = New tblPhone() With { _
            .ID = phone.ID, _
            .PhoneNumber = phone.Number, _
            .Extension = phone.Extension, _
            .TypeID = phone.TypeID, _
            .InsertDate = DateTime.Now, _
            .InsertUser = user, _
            .PersonID = contact.PersonContact.ID _
        }
        dc.tblPhones.InsertOnSubmit(exists)
    End If
  'Do I need to Save here???
  dc.SubmitChanges()
  Next
End If
```

Comment: Have you tried running the code with the update there and also with the update after the end of the loop to see where it works, and where it doesn't?  It seems like a fairly simple way to find out.

Comment: I don't see any reason why it wouldn't work outside the loop.